# What my Javascript object inherits from?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

If I have a function object:

```
function Calculator()
{
// some code
}
```

and then I instantiate with:

```
var calc=new Calculator();
```

Is it correct to say that my calc:

1. is a Calculator object (and inherits from Object object)?
2. inherits from Calculator object (and this in turn inherits from Object object)?

Thanks for clarifying this, cheers,

Comment: Maybe this answer will shed some light on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941  or the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain As others suggested; it would be wise to get an understanding of how prototype works in JS (see first link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every variable is an `Object` and thus has the methods and properties of an `Object`.  However, technically there is no true inheritance in JavaScript since it is a prototypal language rather than classical. But, because everything is an object and everything is mutable, you can mimic inheritance by assigning properties of one object to another object. See jQuery's `extend` method or CoffeeScript's class extension.

But, to answer your question:

1. Yes, `calc` is an instance of `Calculator`, meaning its prototype is `Calculator`.
2. No, see above

Comment: Dart contains much more rigorous classes, and generally tries to fix the weaknesses of javascript as a language. https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#classes

Comment: I actually like the fact that you can create your own "classes" on the fly with JavaScript. It can get you into trouble if you don't know what you're doing but if you're aware of the potential pitfalls then it's a pretty cool feature.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... my understanding is that it *is* a Calculator object, but inheritance is not really a fair term.

It is *an instance* of the Calculator object, which is in turn an instance of object. But since they are not classes as one would traditionally imagine, the term "inherit" is not technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in JavaScript "inherit" from the type `Object`. I put the word inherit in quotes because it's not classical inheritance, but prototypical inheritance because JavaScript is a prototype based language.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) (Seriously, because this won't make complete sense unless you understand prototypes).

Now, the simple answer to your question is that `new Calculator()` creates an instance of `Calculator` which inherits from `Object`. So number 1 is *little* closer. Number 2 is wrong because the calculator object doesn't inherit from itself. It's an `is-a` relationship.

Now there's actually one more piece: the function type. In reality, our "inheritance" in *classical terms* looks like this:

`Calculator` **<-** `Function` **<-** `Object` (**<-** stands for `inherits from`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no idea of `inheritance` per say in JavaScript. Your `Calculator` thing is basically an object and it has a property called `prototype`, which is used as, well, a prototype for all instances of the `Calculator` object.

basically `calculator = new Calculator` will be an instance of `Calculator`, but internally all it's properties (until you explicitly change them) will point to `Calculator.prototype`. In other words, a new `calculator` is pretty much the same object as `Calculator.prototype` but with a different object-id inside of the JavaScript interpreter.

So, in the end `calculator` is an instance of `Calculator` and eventually `Object`, but it does not 'inherit' from `Calculator`, coz there is no inheritance, there are the object prototypes which can be instances of anything.